# onResume works even if activity is started

Tags: android, onresume, application-restart

I have an onPause and an onResume, see the two:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    String str = "";

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    for (int i = 0; i<prefs.getAll().size(); i++){
        str = prefs.getString(String.valueOf(i), "");
        meds.add(str);
        adap.add(str);
        adap.notifyDataSetChanged();}}


  @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    for (int i = 0; i<meds.size(); i++){
        editor.putString(String.valueOf(i), meds.get(i));
        String str1 = editor.toString();
        String str = prefs.getString("0", "");

    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

Now this works fine whenever I really want to resume the activity -say, the user presses the backbutton.

However, when I completely restart the app (as in: shut down the program, run again), apparently onResume is called because my Data are set to those saved in onPause.

Am I just using the wrong method? 
When actually restarting the app, I want to start with my default data and not with what is saved in onPause.

Comment: See [Activity LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) `OnResume` is always called whenever you launch a new activity.

Comment: Hm. So if I do not want to have my data when restarting the app I have to destroy them in the onDestroy? because onDestroy is called when the program stops?

Comment: Actually [onDestroy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) is not reliable and might not be called in some conditions like when OS kills your activity due to memory requirements.

Comment: So I know now what I am doing wrong but not how to do it correctly. Is there a variable or sth. which I can call in onCreate to check if the activity starts for the first time during the running of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnResume` is always called whenever you launch a new activity. You can see this from [Activity LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). If you do not want to have your data when restarting the app, use [isFinishing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing%28%29) method inside `onPause` and if it returns `true` clear everything before closing the `Activity`.

> `isFinishing()` checks whether this activity is in the process of finishing, either because you called finish() on it or someone else has requested that it finished.

Comment: Thank you, just testing. I suppose this does not work when I simply shut down the emulator or the phone, does it? If there is no time to call the method....

Comment: You tried shutting down the phone when you are still on the activity? It doesn't call `onPause` ?

Comment: Yes I tried that and you are, of course, correct, onPause is not called, write that as an answer and I will accept it. My bad - I should have overriden onBackPressed instead of onPause in the first place. So what should I do with this question now, what would be acceptable on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

1. in **onCreate**() set the default values .
2. in **OnResume**() get the latest values and update the the values of
   **meds** and **adap**
3. in **OnPause**() save your preferences.. that is whatever you are
   doing now..
4. you need not to clear the preferences them in **onDestroy**() ,
   since there is no guarantee that the system call **onDestroy()**

Comment: ahm.....that is EXACTLY what I am doing now. What happens then is: app starts, Activity runs onCreate, sets defaultvalues. THEN runs onResume, updates my Values. and THAT is exactly what I do not want.

Comment: since you don't need to maintain the previous app state ..don't use preferences at all , instead use some member variable to temporarily store your values, when the activity switches from onPause() to onResume() .hopes this suits your requirement :)